# How do i split a single column with LONG data into different columns (in Oracle) based off size

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What I'm starting with:
    (Column 1)FileName.xml (Column 2)a very long LONG datatype string exists here.

What I need: 
    (Column 1) FileName.xml (Column 2)LONG characters up to 2K (Column 3) LONG characters up to 4k (Column 4) LONG Characters from 4k-8k (Column 5) LONG Characters from 8k-12k ... (so on and so forth)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `SUBSTR`?

Comment: You cant use `SUBSTR`directly. Check the solution described [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:665224430110)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the long data is stored as `CLOB` datatype, YOu can make use of the package `dbms_lob`

`dbms_lob.substr` will meet your need.

e.g: dmbs_lob.sunstr(colname,2000,1) will give you first 2K character.

Here param1 = column_name, param2 = No. of characters, param3 = offset